# Why does `from ruamel.yaml import CSafeDumper` throw an import error when executed on python3.11?

Tags: python, yaml, ruamel.yaml

Create a `test.py` that contains

```
import sys
print(sys.version)
from importlib.metadata import version
print(f"ruamel.yaml version {version('ruamel.yaml')}") 

from ruamel.yaml import CSafeDumper
```

Running `python3.11 test.py` on will generate

```
3.11.3 (main, Apr  5 2023, 14:14:37) [GCC 11.3.0]
ruamel.yaml version 0.17.22
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/victory/test.py", line 6, in <module>
    from ruamel.yaml import CSafeDumper
ImportError: cannot import name 'CSafeDumper' from 'ruamel.yaml' (/home/victory/venv_3.11/lib/python3.11/site-packages/ruamel/yaml/__init__.py)
```

`python3.10 test.py` on the other hand, returns

```
3.10.6 (main, Mar 10 2023, 10:55:28) [GCC 11.3.0]
ruamel.yaml version 0.17.22
```

I don't know if this is a bug or if something has changed in ruamel.yaml in the latest python version. https://pypi.org/project/ruamel.yaml/0.17.22/ doesn't mention anything about this as far as i can tell.

Comment: For what usage do you import the `CSafeDumper`?

Comment: 0.17.23 has been released and that automatically installs `ruamel.yaml.clib` for Python 3.7-3.11.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From the GCC 11.3.0, I assume you are running on Linux. You don't describe how you installed, but it looks like you only have ruamel.yaml installed and not `ruamel.yaml.clib`, which is needed for the `CSafeDumper` to become active.

For Python 3.10 that installation of `ruamel.yaml.clib` is automatic, but for Python 3.11 it is not (it will be in the next release of `ruamel.yaml`).

On a machine running Ubuntu 22.04, in a freshly created virtualenv:

```
➜ ~ /opt/util/rytest2/bin/python -m pip list               
Package          Version
---------------- -------
pip              22.3.1
ruamel.yaml      0.17.22
ruamel.yaml.clib 0.2.7
setuptools       65.5.0
➜ ~ /opt/util/rytest2/bin/python            
Python 3.11.3 (main, Apr 13 2023, 08:44:49) [GCC 11.3.0] on linux
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> from ruamel.yaml import CSafeDumper
>>> print(CSafeLoader)
<class 'ruamel.yaml.cyaml.CSafeDumper'>
>>>
```

So just explicitly installing `ruamel.yaml.clib` should do the trick.

Comment: I installed `ruamel.yaml` using pip. I've confirmed that `pip install ruamel.yaml.clib` fixes this. Thanks!